# Instantiate a class in a separate thread without a compile time warning

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it possible to instantiate a class in a separate thread without a compile time warning?

For example the below code gives the compile time error "Use of unassigned local variable BECheck". I would rather keep AvailabilityCheckBase abstract and not assign it some dummy variable. Creating both BTCheck and BECheck is slow which is why I need it threaded.

```
    public static AvailabilityCheckBase ByDSL(string dsl)
    {
        AvailabilityCheckBase BECheck;
        AvailabilityCheckBase BTCheck;

        Thread BEThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => BECheck = new BEAvailabilityCheck(dsl)));
        Thread BTThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => BTCheck = new BTAvailabilityCheck(dsl)));

        BEThread.Join();
        BTThread.Join();

        return BECheck.Merge(BTCheck);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't this fix your compile error? :

change

```
    AvailabilityCheckBase BECheck;
    AvailabilityCheckBase BTCheck;
```

to

```
    AvailabilityCheckBase BECheck = null;
    AvailabilityCheckBase BTCheck = null;
```

Answer (score 4):

The language has no knowledge of the `Thread` constructor or the `Join` method: it can't tell that you will definitely assign values to both variables before `Join` returns. If you want to keep the current approach, you'll need to assign values to the variables first. I agree this is slightly ugly, but it's the only way of keeping the compiler happy here.

(It's not clear why you're creating *two* new threads here, given that your original thread is then blocking on both of them, by the way.)

A better approach if you're using .NET 4 would be to use `Task<T>`, which effectively gives you the "promise" of a value:

```
Task<AvailabilityCheckBase> beCheck =
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new BEAvailabilityCheck(dsl));
Task<AvailabilityCheckBase> btCheck =
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new BTAvailabilityCheck(dsl));

return beCheck.Result.Merge(btCheck.Result);
```

It's worth becoming familiar with `Task<T>` and the TPL in general, as the new async features in C# 5 are heavily dependent on them.

Answer (score 2):

In order to call `BECheck.Merge` in your last line, `BECheck` should be initialized, and the compiler doesn't know it will be created before `Thread.Join`.

Try writing

```
    AvailabilityCheckBase BECheck = null;
    AvailabilityCheckBase BTCheck = null;
```

in the first lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the values to `null` you should see the message disappear, this would be good practice. There also doesn't appear to be any checking to make sure that the initialisations worked, you should probably include a check for BECheck and BTCheck still being null at the end of the function before you try to return to avoid an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)'s:

```
 Task<AvailabilityCheckBase> BETask = new Task<AvailabilityCheckBase>(() => BECheck = new BEAvailabilityCheck(dsl));
 Task<AvailabilityCheckBase> BTTask = new Task<AvailabilityCheckBase>(() => BECheck = new BTAvailabilityCheck(dsl));

 BETask.WaitAll(BETask,BTTask);
 AvailabilityCheckBase BECheck = BETask.Result;
 AvailabilityCheckBase BTCheck = BTTask.Result;
```